# Incrementing/decrement with dynamic value in Vue Slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using [Vue Slider](https://nightcatsama.github.io/vue-slider-component/example/) and I want to increase the slider to the next index and so on. Currently, it increments by 1, as 1 is hardcoded in the parameters of the setIndex Function. If I pass a variable, it causes an error. I believe the function setIndex doesn't accept a variable name.

```
<button @click="setIndex('m-slider', 1)">+</button>

setIndex(name, num) {
  let slider = this.$refs[name];
  slider.setIndex(num);
}
```

How Can I make the button click increment/decrement to every click to next index in the slider and hardcode value?

Comment: Did you add a `ref="m-slider"` on the `vue-slider` element?

Comment: @jom yes. it works but increments to next index only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to have a reference to the old/previous index to increment from.

```vue
<button @click="goToSlide('m-slider')">+</button>
<button @click="goToSlide('m-slider', false)">-</button>

data() {
  return {
    slides: []
  }
},

methods: {
  goToSlide(name, next = true) {
    let slider = this.$refs[name];
    let offset, currentIndex = slider.getIndex();

    if (next) {
      offset = Math.min(this.slides.length - 1, currentIndex + 1);
    } 
    else {
      offset = Math.max(0, currentIndex - 1);
    }

    slider.setIndex(offset);
  }
}
```

Comment: great. when I do decrement ( - 1), it doesn't work. It throws error. why is that?

Comment: @Nofel It should, can you post your updated code please?

Comment: `    goToPrevSlide(name) {
      let slider = this.$refs[name];
      slider.setIndex(slider.getIndex() - 1);
    }`

Comment: I did, don't know why code formarrting isn't working.

Comment: @Nofel Well, that really should work, can you put a debugger and check the index? I edited my answer to handle both increment and decrement.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. It was misspelled. Thanks, do you think I should put a .length check of it so it doesn't go out of range?

Comment: @Nofel You could, or simply do `Math.min(total_slides, current_index)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188340/discussion-between-nofel-and-jom).